# How to address a worksheet with Data from Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, worksheet

I am facing following problem:

I have written code to read a range of data, store the data in an array and afterwards insert worksheets with the name from the array. Works fine, code is as follows:

```
For intZaehler = 0 To UBound(arrGliederungsebenen) - 1
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("7_Steuern")).Name = arrGliederungsebenen(intZaehler)
```

arrGliederungsebenen has stored the Data, that I want the new sheets to be named with. I have keept naming simple:

```
arrGliederungsebenen(0) = 1 
arrGliederungsebenen(1) = 1.2 
arrGliederungsebenen(2) = 1.3 
arrGliederungsebenen(3) = 2.1 and so forth
```

Next, I want to paste a previously copied template into the newley inserted sheets. The problem I face now, is how to address the newly added sheets properly: 
Unfortunately 
`Activesheet.paste Destination:=Worksheets(arrGliederungsebenen(intZaehler).Name).Range("A1:0354").Offset(, 24`) doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me, how to address a worksheet's name properly with the data from an array?

Comment: `arrGliederungsebenen(intZaehler)` is a String (I assume), so `arrGliederungsebenen(intZaehler).Name` doesn't mean anything. Try removing the `.Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to set a `Worksheet` object to the current sheet I'm adding (in my code `Dim Sht As Worksheet`), it makes the code much shorter and cleaner, and easier to debug.

And just for this example, I used `Sheets("7_Steuern").Range("C7:E9")` to copy and paste per sheet.

**Code** (tested)

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultipleCreateSheets()

Dim intZaehler As Integer
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim arrGliederungsebenen(3) As String

arrGliederungsebenen(0) = 1
arrGliederungsebenen(1) = 1.2
arrGliederungsebenen(2) = 1.3
arrGliederungsebenen(3) = 2.1

For intZaehler = 0 To UBound(arrGliederungsebenen) - 1
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("7_Steuern"))
    Sht.Name = arrGliederungsebenen(intZaehler)

    Sheets("7_Steuern").Range("C7:E9").Copy Destination:=Sht.Range("A1:O354").Offset(, 24)        
Next intZaehler

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Shai - the sht.Name step was what I was looking for! Unfortunately I cannot upvote yet.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `.Name` for? Seems false to me.

`Destination:=Worksheets(arrGliederungsebenen(intZaehler)`**.Name**`).Range("A1:0354").Offset(, 24)`

--->

```
Destination:=Worksheets(arrGliederungsebenen(intZaehler)).Range("A1:0354").Offset(, 24)
```